# Remove the vertical borders of a table row

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
line 1\\
\hline \\
\hline
line 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The code draws a tabular as follows (please ignore the font and background colours):

[image]

I would like to remove the right border and the left border of the line 2, so that it appears to have two tables (one for line 1 and the other for line 3), does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` in the second line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
line 1\\
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}\\
\hline
line 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use a `\fbox` (provided the contents all have same width).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\fbox{line 1}\\
             \\
\fbox{line 3} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]