# Remove border of particular whole row (with text) in a table

Tags: tables, border

I am trying to draw the following table:

[image]

So far I tried this:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        it & was & the & best & of & times & worst & age & wisdom \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

How to remove the table border of the second row containing texts in columns unchanged.
I got this solution, but it does not suit this case: [Remove the vertical borders of a table row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225479/243840)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most rudimentary approach would be to wrap each cell that needs to have its column specification changed inside a `\multicolumn{1}{<new col spec>}`. Based on your example, all should have a change from `c|` to `c`, which is simplified through a macro `\mc`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{9}{ c| } }
    \hline
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
    \mc{it} & \mc{was} & \mc{the} & \mc{best} & \mc{of} & \mc{times} & \mc{worst} & \mc{age} & \mc{wisdom}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The inclusion of [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array) is not necessary, but provides better rule alignment/joins within a `tabular`.

Comment: Great explanation. +1

Comment: What about the same width of the columns in this table? I want to make the column width the same for all columns.

Comment: @mmr: If you just want some fixed width, use `wc{2.5em}` in your column specification (where you choose a suitable length; I used `2.5em`). If you want it to (say) automatically fill to the widest element, you can measure that element (`\newlength{\maxwordlen} \settowidth{\maxwordlen}{wisdom}`) and use that as the column width (`wc{\maxwordlen}`).

Answer (score 3):

Simple is width `tabularray` package. Its `tblr` table and `X` columns enables simple code for what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{hline{1,2}={solid}, vlines={1}{solid}, % define lines in the first row
               colspec   = {*{9}{X[c]}},              % column specification: X, centered 
               colsep    = 1pt                        % column separation  
               }
1   & 1   & 1   & 1    & 1  & 1     & 0     & 0   & 0       \\
it  & was & the & best & of & times & worst & age & wisdom 
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]